# Retrieving multiple values from Listbox

Tags: java, swing, list, awt, jlist

How to retrieve multiple values from list box and saving it to mysql database. Am using netbeans. Can anyone help me regarding this.

Regards
Prasath

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Whats a ListBox? I'm not familiar with this Java class.

Comment: which  list box? and what you have done, how you doing it ,in what environment you trying do.Provide enough details else no one will able to help you out

Answer (score 2):

You may use `java.awt.List.getSelectedItems()` (for AWT component) method or `javax.swing.JList.getSelectedValuesList()` (Swing comonent) methods if selection mode is set to multiple. For more info read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) pages.